# buffered reader skips first line for some reason

Tags: bufferedreader

Hi in my java file i have a buffered reader, that is reading through a comma seperated file, and it is working perfectly, however, it is skipping the first line completely. the very first line of the csv file isnt being sorted in the code...

however, if i go to the first line in notepad++ of the csv file and press enter to move the first line to line 2 and leave line 1 blank it works perfectly and reads everything...

any idea on why this might be happening?

```
br.readLine();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
```

is how im writing it..

Comment: what is that `br.readLine()` isolated at the beginning of your code? Show the complete relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling `readLine()` before the loop and throwing the result away.

Solution: don't.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do like this. It is reading twice which is skipping the first line.

```
String policyUser;
while(reader.readLine() !=null){
        policyUser = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(policyUser);
    }
```

Do this:

```
while((policyUser=reader.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(policyUser);
    }
```